# In macOS can I show the program name in the title bar?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

If I have a terminal window open and edit a file with vi, or cat a file.

And I have textedit open with that or a similar file.

The windows look very similar.

The terminal doesn't say terminal in the window, though does at least say 'bash' at the top, or would say vi if I opened vi). Though the textedit window does not even say that.

I have to click a textedit window and look to the top of the screen, to see that it's textedit.

[image]

I don't need the whole menubar attached to the window. But there is a program called MenuEverywhere which would in theory help me since apparently it does at least attach the program name to a window.

[image]

But when I try to install it it says

> You can't use this version of the application 'menueverywhere' with
>   this version of macOS.

I am on 10.12.6

Comment: I see no tag for OSX 10.12 / Sierra.  I don't know if macOS is the correct tag for OSX 'cos technically Mac OS may be the thing before OSX, but anyway. I guess maybe there is a tag issue 'cos there's no general OSX tag.

Comment: What about just changing the theme of your Terminal slightly?

Comment: @JMY1000 the textedit window is the one most poorly named

Comment: Two notes: 1) OS X was renamed to macOS with the release of Sierra. 2) MenuEverywhere was last updated in 2012 & is unlikely to still work.

Answer (score 0):

To rename your Terminal window, you can try to copy/paste the following command in the Terminal:

`echo 'echo -n -e "\033]0;TERMINAL\007"' >> ~/.bash_profile;source !$`

It will insert a new line in your `~/.bash_profile` (so it will be permanent) that rename your Terminal title, then source the file to make it effective.

You can later edit your `~/.bash_profile` to change the title as you wish.

Comment: good for terminal, but that doesn't solve the fact that textedit doesn't identify that it is textedit. And my comment on my question says that textedit is most poorly named.